# Extract pairs of variables with high correlation

Tags: r, correlation

I have an input variable `X` and I'm trying to extract the pairs of variables in `X` with a high correlation (>0.9) between each other. So far, I'm using the `cor` function to calculate the correlation between the variables, but I can't see a clear way to get a list/data frame of the pairs of variables that have a high correlation between each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`which(..., arr.ind=TRUE)` is the key.

Make up some data:

```r
set.seed(101)
X <- matrix(rnorm(500), nrow=10,
        dimnames=list(NULL, outer(LETTERS,1:2,paste0)[1:50]))
cc <- cor(X)
```

`range(cc[cc<1])` shows values from -0.82 to 0.87; I'll select values with  `abs(cc)>0.8`; `row(cc) < col(cc)` will select only values from the upper triangle.

```r
w <- which(abs(cc)>0.8 & row(cc)<col(cc), arr.ind=TRUE)
## reconstruct names from positions
high_cor <- matrix(colnames(cc)[w],ncol=2)
```

```r
high_cor
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "G1" "H1"
[2,] "F1" "N1"
[3,] "T1" "Z1"
[4,] "U1" "A2"
[5,] "Q1" "C2"
[6,] "M1" "O2"
```